# I am unable to get all the links present on the page

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, urllib, user-agent

I am using beautifulsoup and urllib to extract a webpage , I have set the user agent and the cookie , and yet i fail to receive all the links from the webpage...
Heres my code :

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import requests
#sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com/search?q=javascript&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93').read()
#soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

'''
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url)
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
'''

url = 'https://github.com/search?q=javascript&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93'


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
           'Cookie' : '_gh_sess=eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiMDNhMGI2NjQxZjY4Mjc1YmQ3ZjAyNmJiODM2YzIzMTUiLCJfY3NyZl90b2tlbiI6IlJJOUtrd3E3WVFOYldVUzkwdmUxZ0Z4MHZLN3M2eE83SzhIdVJTUFVsVVU9In0%3D--4485d36d4c86aec01cde254e34db68005193546e 
           logged_in: no'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(response.cookies)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(url.get('href'))
```

Is there something I'm missing? Inside a browser I get the links to all the code whereas in the script I get only a few of the links , none with the code...

[The webpage opening perfectly in the browser...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP7c1.png)

Comment: `Must include at least one user, organization, or repository` this shows in the page.

Comment: For me it opens up in the browser...

Comment: use a completely new browser session and copy that url (without being logged in)

Comment: What will that do @eLRuLL ?